# how to transfer all data from database to texbox in C# windows application?

Tags: c#

im using access database for my C# application as database,and i create 1 database and  1 windows form application in c#, and there are some textboxes,is it possible inserting all data from database into textboxes by using "SELECT "statement??????how can i do??i need help..

Comment: Avoid access if at all possible.  Sql Server Compact is the preferred alternative.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is -- fill the datatable with this select query and asign each value of this datatable to each textbox.

THis might help you

[How to fill a DataTable with the result of a LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393026/how-to-fill-a-datatable-with-the-result-of-a-linq)